# Find special chart on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to build a chart like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nStTc.png)

Drag the red point or two blue lines on the left chart, then the chart will generate the second one on the right.
Please advice me how to do with highcharts or other chart library. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in Highcharts, and implementation will be not so easy, but I'm not saying it's not possible. In order to achieve the similar effect, you can use `renderer` feature, generate the circle and lines. Then change their attributes (position and dimensions), when dragging the circle. For example:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        var chart = this,
          circleWidth = 5,
          circleInitPos = {
            x: 100,
            y: 100
          },
          lineWidth = 2,
          indicator = chart.renderer.g('indicator').attr('zIndex', 5).add(),
          leftLine = chart.renderer.rect(0, circleInitPos.y, circleInitPos.x, lineWidth)
          .attr({
            fill: 'blue'
          })
          .add(indicator),
          bottomLine = chart.renderer.rect(circleInitPos.x, circleInitPos.y, lineWidth, chart.containerHeight - circleInitPos.y)
          .attr({
            fill: 'blue'
          })
          .add(indicator),
          circle = chart.renderer.circle(100, 100, circleWidth)
          .attr({
            fill: 'red'
          }).add(indicator);

        circle.drag = false;

        chart.container.onmousemove = function(e) {
          if (circle.drag) {
            let normalizedEvent = chart.pointer.normalize(e),
              groupPos = indicator.getBBox(),
              leftLineLen = chart.plotWidth - e.chartX,
              bottomLineLen = chart.plotHeight - e.chartY;

            // Recalculate dimensions
            leftLine.attr({
              width: e.chartX,
              y: e.chartY
            })
            bottomLine.attr({
              height: chart.containerHeight - e.chartY,
              y: e.chartY,
              x: e.chartX
            })
            circle.attr({
              x: e.chartX,
              y: e.chartY
            })
          }
        }

        circle.element.onmousedown = function() {
          circle.drag = true
        }

        circle.element.onmouseup = function() {
          circle.drag = false
        }

      }
    }
  },
```

I prepared the example which shows how to do it, so here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/rgs4v5az/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer